# How to output a lot of lists with data into one giant list after reading in multiple files using glob.glob?

Tags: python, file-io

I'm trying to figure out how to output some data into a large list after reading in multiple files and doing some analysis on them. My actual script is hundreds of lines long so I'll just summarize:

```
for input_file in glob.glob(os.path.join(input_path, '*.csv')):
     data1 = []
     data2 = []
     fileName = base = os.path.basename(input_file)
     with open(input_file, 'r', newline='') as f:
          reader = csv.reader(f)

     #really long for loop doing stuff to fill the data# lists for 
     #each file such as file1.csv, file2.csv etc.

      new_header = ["File name", "data1", "data2"]
      #for row in something....?
           #fill all_data with the filenames and data in this format (see link)
            #http://dpaste.com/23YFSG7.txt
```

Ok so the [link](http://dpaste.com/23YFSG7.txt) shows the output I want in those 3 columns, but I don't know how to get there. So far with my script I have already stored the data I want for each filename, data1 = [] and data2 = [] lists but I can't quite figure out how to combine them all into one giant list for ease of writing to a file later on.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to merge the lists horizontally?

```
first_row = True
for r1, r2 in zip(data1, data2):
    if first_row:
        print(input_file, r1, r2)  # write co CSV file...
        first_row = False
    else:
        print("\t", r1, r2)
```

Comment: Seems to work fine but whats the first_row = True and False statements for? How do they work in the context of your script? Thanks

Comment: You want file name only in the first row for each file

Comment: Thank you, it makes sense now. I have now progressed to outputting the results to a file however the header seems to be showing up for each file. I have tried to include a variable with one_header = True like this here: http://dpaste.com/164R131, but the header still shows up multiple times. How do I suppress the header to the first row only?